# Defining a region in Mathematica

Tags: numerical-integration, regions, physics

I have two functions which are eigenvalues:
$$
E_+= a*x-\sqrt{(b-x^2-y^2)^2+d*(x^2+y^2)}$$
...and...
$$ E_-= a*x+\sqrt{(b-x^2-y^2)^2+d*(x^2+y^2)}.
$$
How do I define a region $\left|E_{\pm}\right|<E_f$ where $E_f$ is a constant and $x,y$ are the variables for the region?

Context: this region is the region inside Fermi surface of a solid state system which shall be my region for integrating a big function using `NIntegrate`.

Comment: What are $a,b,d$? You must supply their *numerical* values.

Comment: I am giving the numerical values while trying to define the region. They are actually complicated variables. If it helps: a=1, b=0.5, c=1 are some typical values.

Comment: and $d$ and $E_f$ please...

Comment: d=1. E_F I shall vary from -5 to 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ImplicitRegion`:

```
region = With[{a = 1, b = 1/2, c = 1, d = .03, Ef = .5},
  With[{sq = Sqrt[(b - x^2 - y^2)^2 + d (x^2 + y^2)]},
   ImplicitRegion[
    Abs[a*x - sq] < Ef && Abs[a*x + sq] < Ef,
    {x, y}
    ]
   ]
  ]
(* test it works and we get a point *)
RandomPoint[region]
(* NIntegrate[f[x,y], {x,y} ∈ region] *)
```

Comment: Check that the region looks sensible given the parameters:
```ListPlot[RandomPoint[region, 500], AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Medium]]```